# double join sql same table

Tags: sql, laravel, join, double

i have a table "payments" which contains the following:
id
client_id
user_id 
and ofcourse for the payments.

i have another table users 
id
firstname 
middlename
lastname
function (client or admin)

im joining users with the following sql query

```
$payments = Payment::findpayments()
    ->select('users.firstname', 'users.middlename', 'users.lastname', 'payments.*')
    ->join('users','payments.client_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->where('payments.id', '=', $id)
    ->get();
```

now im getting the firstname etc from the client but i need to get the firstname middlename lastname twice for the client and admin does sombody have any idea how to double join the same table?

Answer (score 0):

You can double join by aliasing. Something in these lines

```
->join('users','payments.client_id', '=', 'users.id')
->join('users as admin','payments.client_id', '=', 'admin.admin_id')
```

Just make sure you join them properly, but as long as you alias them, I think it should be ok.

Just keep in mind you need to also alias them in the select like

```
->join('users','payments.client_id', '=', 'users.id')
->join('users as admin','payments.client_id', '=', 'admin.admin_id')
->select('users.name', 'admin.name as admin_name')
```

Comment: Thanks i will try it !

Comment: Cool, if it works, you dont forget to mark my answer. Thanks :)